# junk values in a LPTSTR string

Tags: visual-c++

I wrote a function to return the extension from a path, It looks like below:

```
 LPTSTR GetExtension(LPCTSTR path1)
{
    CString str(path1);
    int length = str.ReverseFind(L'.');
    str = str.Right(str.GetLength()-length);

    LPTSTR extension= str.GetBuffer(0);
    str.ReleaseBuffer();

    return extension;

}
```

I checked the statement and found that extension have a valid value(.txt) while returning but when i use the following statement in main method like below

```
LPTSTR extension = GetExtension(L"C:\\Windows\\text.txt");
```

The variable extension is having the following junk values:
ﻮ

> ﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮ䞐瀘嗯᠀骰PꬰP⚜叕u

Can anyone tell me what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to a released buffer.  *And* the buffer is a local variable of the function.  Both big no-nos.  Change the signature to

```
 size_t GetExtension(LPCTSTR path, LPTSTR buffer, size_t bufferSize)
```

so that you can copy the result into *buffer*.

Or return a CString or std::wstring, you're using C++, not C.  Using TCHAR is also a heavily outmoded way to handle strings, the last non-Unicode version of Windows died a timely death 12 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have my compiler with me, but may be you are probably getting the buffer and storing a location of it. Then you release it while LPTSTR is still pointing to one location.

Or may be LPTSTR is on the stack while while you look at it inside the function. On exiting the function you are loosing it.